# A full div width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a div that will take the width of the full-screen. I can manage the div margin and width but I want it to be responsive (using bootstrap), it wont be if i manage the problem changing the width and margin using pixels. I have tried doing the method I have seen: body {margin: 0; padding: 0} but it doesn't work. Any tips are greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far can you show a your html / css ?

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap with full with? Do you mean `container-fluid`?

You can do the following

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about bootstrap grid system here: [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: I understand the bootstrap grid, but there some kinds of margins on the sides. And if I manually add the margin-left so the edge of my div touches the edge of the screen, when i make the screen shorter (col-sm), it changes completely

Comment: @John Think you should edit your post, with a more detailed question, and show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
eg:div {width: 100%};
div {width: calc(100% - 20px)}
```

css3 calc().
try it instead